# plt.show() doesn't render the image on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

When I'm trying to plot some data on jupyter notebook with pyspark environment (on python3.6) builded over EMR instance, the plot doesn't appears. Summarizing: When I run the `plt.show()` command the plot don't appear.

First I tried putting `%matplotlib inline` at the beginning but the plot appears. Then I tried changing the backend... No luck! Only the "Agg" backend works, when I tried others the code crush.

This is the same code I'm trying to plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.switch_backend('agg')
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()
```

**Output**

Nothing...

I also read that for plotting I need to use "%matplotlib inline" but the problem with this is that the variables defined on others cells  don't exist on `%matplotlib inline` cell.

Let's see...

*Cell 1*

```py
dummy_var = 10
```

*Cell 2*

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()
print(dummy_var)
```

**Output**

> NameError: name 'dummy_var' is not defined.

*Disclaimer:*
Being fair, the `%matplotlib inline` command works fine but I also need the outside variables, for plotting them.

*Cell 3*

```py
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()
```

**Output**

[The plot]

This is my notebook, with the error and the examples...
[image: Image with the error]

Comment: Odd, but when i put the last two lines in different cell, it works. Can you check?

Comment: Did you run `%matplotlib inline`?

Comment: Yes! Is really odd. When I run the same code on my local jupyter notebook i haven't any problem but when I do the same on emr jupyter notebook with pyspark the error occur.

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` should only be imported once at the top of the notebook and not in every cell.  Do not import it in the cell from which you're producing a plot.  I also never use `%matplotlib inline`

Comment: Alexander, as I said, when I run %matplotlib  inline works perfectly, but without the outside variables. I already tried running %matplotlib inline in the first cell and the same error

Comment: (1) According to the screenshot you defined the variable in cell 16 and try to use it in cell 10. Of course variables must be defined *before* using them. (2) The `agg` backend cannot show a figure; it can only be used for saving.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest and which backend should I use? Thx!

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use interactive backends in pyspark? You can try `%matplotlib notebook` but it may fail for good reasons.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to display a plot using data from spark by running the following in a separate cell:

```
%matplot plt
```

That is courtesy of the README sample in the [sparkmagic github page](https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic)

Comment: Finally something worked!! Thanks a lot. Been searching for hours. The pyspark notebook on EMR had not been showing any plot. Tried %matplotlib inline, plt.show() but no success.

Answer (score 0):

This used to happen to me too, but what i used is this instructions:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

just in the cell you did make your imports

Also a good behavior to have with notebooks is to always put your imports in the same cell at the top of the notebook.

Comment: Thanks @moctarjallo, this suggestion works well for me using Jupyter with Zeppelin!